# Proving a subset is a subspace to a Vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

let set : $V=\{f \mid f \colon [0,1] \to R\}$

be a Vector Space such as:

$\forall x \in R : (f+g)(x)=f(x) + g(x)$

$\forall a \in R , \forall x \in R : (af)(x) = af(x) $

Is $W=\{f \in V \mid f({1 \over 2})-3f({\pi \over 4})= f(0)\}$
a subspace of the vector space $V$? What exactly do I need to show, and what tools do I have for it?

Plus I'm asked to think about: is the set of all continuous functions in $V$, a subspace of $V$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Can you show that the constant zero function belongs to $W$?
2. Can you show that, if $f,g\in W$, then $f+g\in W$?
3. Can you show that, if $f\in W$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$, then $af\in W$?
4. Can you do the same verifications for the set of continuous functions?

Hint for 2. Set $h=f+g$. Then
$$
h(\tfrac{1}{2})-3h(\tfrac{\pi}{4})=
f(\tfrac{1}{2})-3f(\tfrac{\pi}{4})+
g(\tfrac{1}{2})-3g(\tfrac{\pi}{4})=
f(0)+g(0)=\dots
$$

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that this set is "closed under vector addition" and "closed under scalar multiplication".

That is, if f and g are two functions in this subset- that is, $f(\frac{1}{2})−3f(\frac{π}{4})=f(0)$ and $g(\frac{1}{2})−3g(\frac{π}{4})=g(0)$- then f+g is also in the subset: $(f+g)(\frac{1}{2})−3(f+ g)(\frac{π}{4})=(f+ g)(0)$

And, if f is any function in this subset, so $f(\frac{1}{2})−3f(\frac{π}{4})=f(0)$ and a is any scalar (number) then af is also in the subset: $af(\frac{1}{2})−3af(\frac{π}{4})=af(0)$